# make website mobile responsive unable to fit element correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is my first time trying to make a website mobile repsonsive and I am walking on fire literally . This is the pic of my app unresponsive on my laptop :

[image]

Now when I try to tweak the css using media queries I get a result like this for 320 px screens(mobile):

[image]

As you can see my blue input boxes move outside of my image instead of fitting inside my black container . I need your help to fix this and some guidance with how to make a website responsive(best practices , a technique , not w3schools plz).
My code for the container with the boxes :

```css
.transparent-box{
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:15%;
    background-color:black;
    height:550px;
    width:70%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.transparent-box p{
    color:white;  
    text-align:center;

}

.transparent-box h1{
    color:white;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    top:30px;
}


#hangman-container{
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
    top:40%;
    left:0%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}


.dash{
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    top:100px;
    padding:20px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 5%;
    background-color: turquoise;
    color:red;
    font-size:40px;
}

.dash:focus{
    opacity:0.8;
}

.island-container{
    width:30%;
    height:200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:35%;
}

.island-img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:1;
}






@media screen and (max-width:320px){
    .transparent-box{
        height: 30%;
        width:80%;
    }
    #island-img{
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width:100%;
        top:40px;
        left:500px;
    }

    .dash{
        margin:3px;
    }

    #hangman-container{
        top:20%;
        
    }

    .dash{
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding:15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="transparent-box" id="t-box">
  <p>Play here </p>
  <h1 id="hidden-word">The word is :
    <span id="random-island"> ΠΑΤΜΟΣ </span>


  </h1>

  <div class="island-container" id="island-c">
    <img class="island-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/A44/EED?text=Island" alt="" />

  </div>

  <form id="hangman-container" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" id="2">
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" id="2">
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" id="2">
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" id="2">
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" id="2">
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" id="2">
  </form>
</div>
```

It should be best to view my example on a full page and test it's mobile view . I would appreciate your help

Comment: In your media queries add `#island-c {width:100%;}` and see whether that fixes your issue

Comment: @ksa It didn't . Do you have something else in mind ?

Comment: check this fiddle, I have made some changes. https://jsfiddle.net/9fcvt8rq/29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to a responsive design – albeit using no media queries – is as follows:

```css
/* resetting elements to use border-box sizing, in order that
   all elements are sized the same way, and that the size of
   the element includes the borders and paddings; also setting
   the border to be zero width and transparent to remove it
   from the elements on the page, along with setting margin
   and padding to 0: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  border: 0 none transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* here we're using CSS Grid display to more easily align
   the contents within this element:
*/
.transparent-box {
  background-color: #000c;
  display: grid;
  /* this places a gap/'gutter' between adjacent grid areas
     (it also works with CSS Flexbox:) */
  gap: 1em;
  /* here we're defining the named grid areas into which
     the child elements will be placed; the strings represent
     named areas, the periods ('.') represent empty areas within
     the grid; in this case used to create margins at either side: */
  grid-template-areas: ". hint ." ". word ." ". island ." ". form .";
  /* defining the width of each column of the grid; the 'fr' unit
     is a fractional unit based on the size of the available space
     within the grid's dimension. 1fr is one unit, 3fr is equal to
     three units, of that space: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  /* here we use the repeat() function to define four rows, each
     row height based on the minimum size required to display the
     content of that row: */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, min-content);
  /* we're centring the element in the page, 5vh from the top of the page
     (1vh is equal to 1% of the viewport's height), with an auto margin
     on both left and right sides which centres the element, and a zero margin
     on the bottom edge: */
  margin: 5vh auto 0 auto;
  /* using padding on the top and bottom edges of the grid to prevent
     the descendants being placed on the top/bottom border: */
  padding: 1em 0;
  /* using the CSS clamp function to specify a width of 70vw
     (like vh, 1vw represents 1% of the viewports width); so
     this is equal to 70% of the viewport's width, but with a
     maximum upper-width of 1000px and a minimum width of 300px: */
  width: clamp(300px, 70vw, 1000px);
}

.transparent-box p {
  color: white;
  /* placing the <p> element in the grid-area named 'hint':  */
  grid-area: hint;
  text-align: center;
}

.transparent-box h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* placing the <p> element in the grid-area named 'word':  */
  grid-area: word;
  text-align: center;
}

.island-container {
  /* setting the display to 'flex' for the contents of this element: */
  display: flex;
  /* placing the <p> element in the grid-area named 'island':  */
  grid-area: island;
  height: 200px;
}

.island-container img {
  /* with the parent-element as display: flex, we can
     use 'margin: auto' to vertically and horizontally
     centre the <img> element within its parent: */
  margin: auto;
}

#hangman-container {
  /* display: flex, in order to allow the child elements
     to be positioned and responsively reflowed as necessary: */
  display: flex;
  /* we set the contents to run horizontally: */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* we allow the contents to wrap to new lines: */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* setting a margin/gutter between adjacent elements: */
  gap: 0.5em;
  /* placing the <p> element in the grid-area named 'form':  */
  grid-area: form;
  /* spacing the elements with equal space between adjacent
     elements and the starting/ending boundaries of the
     element: */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

/* I've added a little extra here for UI purposes: */
.dash,
.dash:placeholder-shown {
  background-color: turquoise;
  border-radius: 5%;
  /* here I've defined two box-shadows, both of which are
     currently unseen as they're entirely transparent
     (using the hexadecimal notation for: #rrggbbaa (#rgba),
     where 'rr'/'r' is red, 'gg'/'g' is green', 'bb'/'b' is
     blue and 'aa'/'a' is alpha: */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #0000, 0 0 0 6px #0000;
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  /* declaring a transition on the 'box-shadow' property,
     lasting '0.3 seconds' with a 'linear' transition: */
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear;
}

/* here we style the :active and :focus styles of the element,
   in order that a user navigating the page without a mouse
   can see which <input> they're interacting with: */
.dash:active,
.dash:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000c, 0 0 0 6px turquoise;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* here we style the <input> elements which are not showing
   their placeholder value, in order that users can differentiate
   between focused/active <input> elements and elements into which
   a value has already been entered: */
.dash:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000c, 0 0 0 6px limegreen;
}

/* styling the colour of the placeholder text: */
.dash::placeholder {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="transparent-box" id="t-box">
  <p>Play here </p>
  <h1 id="hidden-word">The word is :
    <span id="random-island"> ΠΑΤΜΟΣ </span>
  </h1>

  <div class="island-container" id="island-c">
    <img class="island-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/A44/EED?text=Island" alt="" />
  </div>

  <form id="hangman-container" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <!-- I've added placeholders to the <input> elements in order that
         users might more easily see that interaction is expected: -->
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" placeholder="?" />
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" placeholder="?" />
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" placeholder="?" />
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" placeholder="?" />
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" placeholder="?" />
    <input class="dash" maxlength="1" placeholder="?" />
  </form>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content).
  - "[Basic Concepts of Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)."
  - [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp).
  - "[Basic concepts of Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)."
  - [CSS `<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).
  - [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).
  - [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).
  - [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
  - [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area)
  - [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas).
  - [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
  - [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
  - [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
  - [`::placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder).
  - [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown).

Answer (score 1):

you will do it `#transparent-box:relative`, `#island-container:absolute`,`#hangman-container:absolute`, so you are going to align `#island-contaner` and `#hangman-container` with `#transparent-container`.don't forget to give 100% of the width of **#island-container**  and **#hangman-container**